# Spinner data accept is mulfunctioning

Tags: android, spinner

I have a spinner which displays both options, but when I accept the female option, it still takes the answer as a male, any suggestions?

```
    List<String> SpinnerArray =  new ArrayList<String>();
    SpinnerArray.add("Male");
    SpinnerArray.add("Female");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, SpinnerArray);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    Spinner Items = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.genderSpinner);
    Items.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerName);
    String selected = Items.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if (selected.equals("Male")) {
        inputGen = "Male";
    }       
    if (selected.equals("Female")){
        inputGen = "Female";
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered using `getSelectedItemPosition()`? Then `if(selected == 0) {.....}` and `else if(selected == 1) {.....}`

Answer (score 1):

Following the [official guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html):

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
   ...

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
        int pos, long id) {
    // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
    // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // Another interface callback
}
```

You can try a `switch` of `position` and then try your same conditions.